# program termination causedfrom getting an non called function out of comment.libxl library involved

Tags: c++, eclipse, optimization, linker, libraries

i have a program with a function that exports an xls file using the libxl library.
In my main i do not call the function.In the cpp that the export function is implemented if the function is commented the program runs properly and prints on console some things.If i bring out the function from under comment the program terminates immediately with out giving me an error.Every time i try to use debug i get this error

> C:Documents and SettingsplatonasWorkspace Eclipse for
>   CHeliostatValidationsrcHeliostatValidation.cpp

which should be

> C:/HeliostatValidation/src/HeliostatValidation.cpp

My basic question is that since i do not call the function why the do i get an error since the function is not in use.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "ValidationController.h"
#include "SettingsHandler.h"


int main() {
SettingsHandler shObj;
shObj.readFile();
shObj.setVariables();
shObj.printSettings();
ValidationController vcObj;

vcObj.calcContrBatch(2013,9,26,8,47,47,Sun::OneYear,Sun::ArcsinMode,Sun::East);


vcObj.printData(vcObj.dataValues);
//  vcObj.exportData(vcObj.dataValues,"file");

return 0;
}
```

and cpp that has the function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "ValidationController.h"
#include <array>
#include "NTP.h"
#include "DayNumber.h"
#include "Heliostat.h"
#include "Data.h"
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "libxl.h"
using namespace libxl;

 void ValidationController::exportData(const vector<Data>& dataVector,string nameOfFile) {

    Book *book = xlCreateBook();
    if(book){
        Sheet *sheet=book->addSheet("Sheet1");
        if(sheet){
            sheet->writeStr(2,2,"Year");
            sheet->writeStr(2,3,"Month");
            sheet->writeStr(2,4,"Day");
            sheet->writeStr(2,5,"DayOfWeek");
            sheet->writeStr(2,6,"LctHour");
            sheet->writeStr(2,7,"Minutes");
            sheet->writeStr(2,8,"Seconds");
            sheet->writeStr(2,9,"TimeDec");
            sheet->writeStr(2,10,"Sun's Elevation");
            sheet->writeStr(2,11,"Sun's Azimuth");
            sheet->writeStr(2,12,"Helio's Pitch");
            sheet->writeStr(2,13,"Helio's Azimuth");

//          int lineMorphing=dataVector.at(0).getDayOfWeek();
//
//          for (unsigned int i=0,m=3;i<dataVector.size();i++,m++){
//              if(dataVector.at(i).getDayOfWeek()!=lineMorphing){
//                  lineMorphing=dataVector.at(i).getDayOfWeek();
//                  m++;
//              }
//              int k=0;
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getYear());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getMonth());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getDay());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getDayOfWeek());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getHour());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getMinutes());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getSeconds());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getTimeInDecimal());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getSunsPitch());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getSunsAzimuth());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getHelioPitch());
//              sheet->writeNum(m,++k,dataVector.at(i).getHelioAzimuth());
//
//          }
//
        }
        nameOfFile.append(".xls");
        const char* fileName=nameOfFile.c_str();
        book->save(fileName);
        book->release();

    }else{
        cout <<"error on book"<<endl;
    }
}
```

i have noticed that every string like "sheet1" has an L before like

```
Sheet *sheet=book->addSheet(L"Sheet1");
```

in the official examples.As for the library i have gone to the Properties-->Build C/C++ -->Settings -->Linker MinGW (at the tab )-->libraries and i have add the path and the name of the library without the extention .lib also i have included the paths of the "include cpp" named folder in libxl files to the compiler includes so the program could see the headers.I have read some post about adding libraries in Eclipse from overflow.

Sorry again main question why a function that is not called in main is responsible for terminating the program.